# Gradient and inner product

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let be $A:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ a linear transformation; $f:\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by: $f(x,y)=\left\langle Ax,y\right\rangle$ and $g(x)=\left\langle Ax,x\right\rangle.$ Determine $grad\ f(x,y)$ and $grad\ g(x).$

Comment: Please, consider sharing your ideas on the problem

Comment: I think this is the gradient of $g$ $grad\ g(x)=\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(x),...,\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(x)\right)$ and for $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ \begin{align*}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x)&=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{g(x+te_i)-g(x)}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\left\langle A(x+te_i),x+te_i\right\rangle-\left\langle A(x),x\right\rangle}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t\left\langle A(x),e_i\right\rangle+t\left\langle A(x),x\right\rangle+t^2\left\langle A(x),e_i\right\rangle}{t}\\
&=\left\langle A(x),x+e_i\right\rangle.
\end{align*}. Bad I am not sure.

Comment: Problem here: $x \in \Bbb R^m$, $Ax \in \Bbb R^n$. Unless $n = m$, the definition of $g$ makes no sense.

Comment: @JorgeGomezRíos That last limit numerator should be $t\left\langle A(x),e_i\right\rangle+t\left\langle A(e_i),x\right\rangle+t^2\left\langle A(e_i),e_i\right\rangle$.

Comment: You are on the right track, though. Now realize $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x) = \langle \nabla_x g, e_i \rangle$, so if you correct the numerator and get the correct limit, then figure out how to express it as the inner product of something with $e_i$, that something will be the expression for $\nabla_x g$.

Comment: Ok @PaulSinclair  \begin{align*} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x)&=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{g(x+te_i)-g(x)}{t}\\ &=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\left\langle A(x+te_i),x+te_i\right\rangle-\left\langle A(x),x\right\rangle}{t}\\ &=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t\left\langle A(x),e_i\right\rangle+t\left\langle A(e_i),x\right\rangle+t^2\left\langle A(e_i),e_i\right\rangle}{t}\\ &=\left\langle A(x),e_i\right\rangle+ \left\langle A(e_i),x\right\rangle\end{align*} But $g$ is not good defined?

Comment: You can go farther. Note what I said earlier about $n = m$ for g to be defined at all, so $A$ is a square matrix. Now do you know how to transfer $A$ from $e_i$ to $x$ in $\langle Ae_i, x\rangle$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that for $\Bbb R^k, \langle Ax, y \rangle = (Ax)^Ty = x^TA^Ty = \langle x, A^T y \rangle$, considering A to be an $n \times n$ matrix and $x, y$ to be column matrices. Also remember that the inner product is symmetric and bilinear.